# how to find a range in linked list when we have upper and lower bound

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

i am trying to implement the linkedList and i already implemented the addition of elements from the TreeSet and also the size of the List through recursion. Now i am trying to find the range of the list when we give the lower and upper bound and i want to implement it through recursion. here is the main class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TreeSet<String> ts;
    ts = new TreeSet<>();
    ts.add("C");
    ts.add("A");
    ts.add("B");
    ts.add("E");
    ts.add("F");
    ts.add("D");
    ts.add("z");
    LinkedList<String> l=new LinkedList<>(ts);
```

and here is the LinkedList Class

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private class Node {
    private T data;
    private Node next;
    private Node(T data)
   {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
   }


}
    private Node head;
    Node current=null;
    int s=0;
    public LinkedList() {
    head=null;
    }
    public HashSet<T> inRange(T lowerBound, T upperBound)
    {

       if(head==null)
       return null;

       if(head.data.compareTo(lowerBound)==0)
       {
           set.add(head.data);
           return inRange(lowerBound,head.next.data);

        }
        if(head.data.compareTo(upperBound)==0)
        {
            return set;
        }
        return set;

    }
```

i think this is not a correct way but i will appreciate every help if someone helps me in making my code correct.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) What's the actual problem? (see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) 2) Your code does not even compile. What is **`set`** in `inRange(T, T)`?

Comment: i didn't mention the all code and "set" is the instance of HashSet. i want to store the elements in HashSet which is in the lower and upper bound which would be already mention.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer i just want to show the range of the elements and the range would be determine from the lower and upper bound and the lower and upper bound would be the elements from the linkedList and the range elements would be store in HashSet. This is what i want. i hope you get it

Comment: is there anyone to help me please?